# How to efficiently cache mysql query in php for this table

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, cakephp

I have a `Posts` table containing the fields `title`, `contents`, `rating`, `no_of_comments`, `author_id`.  When a user downvotes the post, the rating field is decremented and vice-versa. 
Also i am caching the display query, which shows the recent posts, and it's related to the table `Authors`. The problem is that the ratings field need to be updated often i.e. there are a lot of upvotes and downvotes. So i need to rebuild the cache every time a user up/down the post. I believe this is a waste, because only one field in the entire cached data is updated. So i want to know is there any workaround this issue. btw i am using file based caching.

Comment: If you normalised your data structure, you would be able to cache the static part - i.e. The "Post", have the "Post Attributes" or whatever you decide to use, being dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. So your solution is to open an ajax request to a PHP that does the following:

**UNTESTED**

```
while (array_pop(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE `ID` = '$latest_id_prediction'"))) == 0) { 
    sleep(10);
}
echo array_pop(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ID` = '$latest_id_prediction'");
```

This will check every 10 seconds if there is a new post, if there is, it will echo out the post information. what you do is make an ajax request to this page without a timeout, and update the page when you get a reply. When you get the reply, open a new connection.

Comment: so, do i need to split up the query to multiple queries? But wouldn't it be a lot harder for php to rebuild the structure(ie finding the correct rating for each post), thus taking extra processing.

Comment: No. Forget about the rating for now, grab everything else and build the page. Now you can grab the rating and figure that out dynamically by selecting only the `rating` from the table.

Comment: oh wait. im showing a list of posts in the front page, where i need both the ratings and posts.

Comment: Then what do you need to cache? If rating is being updated, you want to update the page without reloading?

Comment: u r technically correct, but im caching the recent posts, i.e. instead of the fetching the recent posts from the database (using select command, which is quite time taking) for every requests, im retrieving the list from the cache. I update the cache only when a new post is submitted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3700/discussion-between-shahal-tharique-and-korvin-szanto)

Answer (score 0):

If you normalised your data structure, you would be able to cache the static part - i.e. The "Post", have the "Post Attributes" or whatever you decide to use, being dynamic.

Number of comments should be derived by counting the number of comments in a "Comments" table.

A solid data structure will help you out alot here.

Comment: i didn't quite get it( it seems a lot). Can u translate it to my case?